# Writing Group members in the form of table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, covers

I was trying to create a cover-page for our assignment. But I don't know how to create [image]

In a best way(with out using too many `\ldots` or with out any `\ldots`).

Comment: try `member\dotfill ID no`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick way to add all group members to a `list of members` and displaying like a `ToC`.

The code uses `expl3` syntax (loaded by `xparse`) and is at the moment a not so pretty mix of `expl3` and traditional `TeX/LaTeX`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofgroupmembers}{%
  \begingroup
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{40pt}%
  \section*{Group Members}
  \markboth{}{}%
  \@starttoc{gmb}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcounter{members}

\renewcommand{\themembers}{\arabic{members}.}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\addgroupmember}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{members} = 0 
  \addtocontents{gmb}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Name}{ID\ \uuline{No}}}
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{members}
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \addtocontents{gmb}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{\themembers}\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist{1}}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
\listofgroupmembers

\chapter{First}
\addgroupmember{Salmon,788878}
\addgroupmember{Mark,5588778}
\addgroupmember{Ramos,444487}
\addgroupmember{Groucho,1}
\addgroupmember{Chico,2}
\addgroupmember{Harpo,3}
\addgroupmember{Zeppo,4}
\addgroupmember{Gummo,5}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's nice to add some space between the `Name` etc. line and the real entries.

Comment: How can I add a space for signature?

Comment: @albo: Where do you want to have a signature?

Comment: At the right side of ID no.

Comment: @albo -- should be possible, but what is the signature then? A name, an abbreviation?

Comment: @Christian_Hupfer: At the right of ID No I want to put the word " signature" and below it a blank space like " ______ " for the respective member.